# QFontMetrics.width() not returning the correct value in linux

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

```
QString folderPath = "/home/Users"
Q_UNUSED(option);
Q_UNUSED(widget);

painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);

painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(16,87,98),2));
painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);

painter->drawRect(m_bounds);
m_pathItem->setPos(m_bounds.topLeft());

QFont font( "Calibri" );
font.setPixelSize(14);
font.setBold(false);
painter->setFont( font );

painter->setPen(QColor(16,87,98));

QFontMetrics fm = painter->fontMetrics();
fm.width(folderPath) // Returns 71
```

When I used the below string pixel returned is different

```
QString folderPath = "/homeUsers!"
fm.width(folderPath) // Returns 73
```

This happens only in linux, windows its working fine

Comment: AFAIK *Calibri* is included only in Windows Vista and later. Did you install it in your Linux installation, so it is available to applications? Else some substitute will be used, and that may have different widths for some characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating the width of a text using a proportional font, where the characters `/` and `!` may indeed have a different widths, so the total width of "/home/Users" may differ from "/homeUsers!".

Obviously this is not the case for the Windows font [*Calibri*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibri), which is available in Windows Vista and later. If you didn't install it in Linux a [substitute](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfont.html#substitute) is used, which may show the given behaviour.

Recommended reading: The detailed description of [QFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfont.html#details). The important part is

> Qt will use the font with the specified attributes, or if no matching font exists, Qt will use the closest matching installed font. The attributes of the font that is actually used are retrievable from a QFontInfo object.